# Django Internationalization gettext() Not Creating message files from JavaScript source code

Tags: django, django-i18n

I am working with django internationalization. I did all setup its working fine in templates and .py files.
I tried to create a translation text in .js file I setup that like [This documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#using-the-javascript-translation-catalog).
After the setup I used the `gettext()` in my js file is not showing the error in console.
Then I use the command to create messages file `django.po` using this command `django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l ta` and the translation text not added in `django.po` file.

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    ...,
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

**js file**

```js
    console.log(gettext('Javascrit gettext')) //Print the text in console it was working.
```

Comment: Try ` makemessages -l de -e js -d djangojs -l ta`

Comment: @Nechoj Not working.

Comment: Did you include the correct settings in `settings.py`? I.e., is the translation working in templates and Python code?

Comment: @Nechoj yeah the translation working fine in templates and python code.

Comment: Did you include `<script src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>` in your base html?

Comment: Btw, using `-d djangojs` the translations go into `djangojs.po`, not `django.po`

Comment: @Nechoj Yes I added script tag. and there was no `djangojs.po`  file created.

Comment: Your process / shell does have the right to create a file `djangojs.po` in the locale path?

Comment: @Nechoj i don't know. but it was create `django.po` file

Comment: Is your js file located inside a dir like `\app_name\static\app_name\js\ `?

Comment: @Nechoj No that was inline script.

Comment: Did you try with js file in such a dir?

Comment: @Nechoj Oh thanks. Now its working. after putting code into `static` folder